# Analog input of Atmega328PB keeps dying

Tags: analog, atmega

We have a quite complicated device which runs on Atmega328PB MCU which is incorporated on the analog of Arduino Nano board. User deflects joystick, and MCU controls stepper motor drivers accordingly, also communicating by Bluetooth. Device consists of the following parts:

1. 12V@2A wall PSU (MeanWell) connectet to Vin of Arduino with 100 uF bypass electrolytic capacitor
2. Industrial APEM joystick with 0.5-4.5V analog outputs (X and Y axis, connected to A0 and A1 analog inputs accordingly).
3. I2C OLED LCD (20x4)
4. Two HC-06 Bluetooth modules
5. Two Allegro A4988 drivers from Pololu connected to a couple of bipolar stepper motors. Vref of drivers is set to 0.25V rendering maximum current of 460 mA.
6. A button, connected to digital input pin D9.
7. Indicator LED, connected to D10.

5 volts for all consumers are supplied by AMS1117 installed on the Arduino board.
We have a repeating problem, that after some time of successful operation, A0 input begins to read strange data. We measured the following resistances:

1. A0 - GND: 210 Ohm
2. A0 - 5V:  1700 Ohm

This resistances are reached gradually from normal several M ohms, not in a single step.
Our only idea was that protection diodes on the input were fried.[image: Pin schematic from datasheet]
DMM shows the following voltage drop:

- D1: 0.155V
- D2: 0.55V

On normal pins values are 0.75V and 0.62V accordingly. 
Moreover, we noticed that two other input pins (A1 and button D9) are also damaged, but to a lesser extent. All output pins are OK.

What can possibly be a reason of such failure? And what actions should be taken to find it out?

---

**ADDED SOME PHOTOS**

[image: General layout]
General view. Power (12V) goes to the gray box, from there goes to the main PCB, where onboard AMS1117 regulator provides 5V, which goes back to joystick. When fully assembled, main board with motors and screen are located in a large plastic enclosure. Big rocker switch provides 12V to Arduino regulator.

[image: Connector board]

PCB inside gray box. Connects joystick, button with LED, 12V power and a cable going to the main PCB.

[image: Main PCB]

Main PCB. That's where Arduino, drivers, motors, BT modules and screen are connected.

---

**THANKS TO EVERYONE** You've guided me to right direction (so I hope). Below are oscillograms recorded during various conditions.

[image: Output of AMS1117 5V regulator after turning on main switch]
Output of AMS1117 5V regulator after turning on main switch

[image: 12V after turning on main switch]
Same for 12V

[image: Voltage on analog input]
Voltage in analog input after turning on main switch. That's probably the perpetrator: undershoot down to -1.28V

[image: Joystick disconnected]
Even worse if I disconnect joystick output from the analog pin. Voltage goes down to -5V. I believe that when connected to MCU, protection diodes are dying while trying to clamp this voltage.

[image: Standalone joystick]
If I power up a standalone joystick (not connected to anything), signal on it's output demonstrates normal behavior.
When system is under normal operation, both 5V and 12V show very high stability under any circumstances (motors idle or running at full speed, BT transmission on and off).

---

**What is causing such dreadful behavior of joystick output, and how to combat it???**

Comment: It might help if you clearly separated whatever parts of the system are on the far side of the radio link.  What sort of environment does the transmitter side that is failing operate in?  Do you have long cable runs?  Industrial machinery?  Welding/plasma cutting/fusion research reactor...

Comment: Can you break the circuit and measure current flow between the joystick and arduino analog input as you sweep through the range?

Comment: Could it be ESD damage? Is the pin broken out to some connector and the joystick connects via a cable and a mating connector?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Bluetooth modules are attached to the same PCB where we put Arduino as a shield. I don't think that these modules are to blame, it is well tested in many projects. Environment is a standard lab.

Comment: @nvuono you mean by DMM as an ammeter? Or using resistor in series and measuring quick voltage drop with oscilloscope?

Comment: What do you mean?  You have *two* bluetooth modules, a joystick input, and a stepper driver chip all on the *same* board?   Why would you do that?  What is powering your stepper drivers?  And what is a "standard lab" - a lab for *what* exactly?

Comment: @ChrisStratton No, I'll draw the layout later and will add it to the original post. BT are attached by ca. 30 cm 4-wire cables (+5V, GND, Tx, Rx) to the main PCB. Drivers and Arduino are attached to this PCB as a shields. Joystick is located in a separate enclosure, and there are several cable connections between it and MCU. Lab is chemistry lab, but device demonstrated same behaviour in office, where air conditioning is probably the worst source of EMI

Comment: @anrieff yes, actually there are several connections between them. How do I detect if it was ESD?

Comment: What's not really making sense is why you have the joystick and the stepper drivers electrically connected by any sort of wires at all.  Your mention of two bluetooth modules made it sound like you had two independent systems, on taking user input, and another doing something.  Sounds like that's not the case (and indeed blueooth might not be a great idea for that).  Anyway, you neglected to answer how the stepper drivers are powered - you definitely *do not* want them running off the same regulator as the Arduino.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I guess we misunderstood each other! MCU controls drivers using joystick and button as input devices. Stepper drivers are powered through same 12V PSU which feeds Arduino's AMS1117. I've checked both 5V rails and 12V with oscilloscope, voltage never drops under any circumstances.

Comment: _"Industrial APEM joystick"_ - APEM make 38 different joystick products. Which one are you using? Can you post a photo of the system showing all wiring between devices?

Comment: It's not voltage *drops* you need to worry about...

Comment: @BruceAbbott added photos. Joystick is APEM 3000 series with 0.5-4.5V output.

Comment: @ChrisStratton added photos and description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it can't be said for sure, your MCU pins could be killed by [ESD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_discharge). The failure mode you describe can be quite typical for ESD damage. You can test this with an ESD tester, but it's easier to install protection and see if the thing still fails. You can use some TVS diodes rated for 5V on the analog inputs. You can also put some resistance, e.g. 100Ω on the input, to limit the static discharge current, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSQPoy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! But what is the source of the ESD? MCU is in the plastic enclosure, and user never touches any contacts or connectors.

Comment: Before you connect the joystick, it may have accumulated some static charge. Depending on which pins mate first - sometimes this static charge flows safely through the ground, but if it's the signal pins, then you have it. What model are the connectors btw?

Comment: The problem is that once system assembled, user doesn't disconnect anything. Connectors are Connfly HU/WF aeries. Apem provides joystick with such connector (HU-7) already mounted.

Comment: @Zhenek: to clarify: after everything is connected, the system works, and then degrades after some use? Or something else?

Comment: I've added some pictures. I guess I've fount the culprit, but I have no idea why it's happening.

Comment: OK, I see it's definitely not ESD. The transient you're seeing is strange, but could be normal (the joystick probably generates negative voltage internally, and during powerup it does leak some of it while the joystick "boots up" so to speak). The suggested protection scheme here should keep your MCU happy. Likely just the resistors will be enough actually.

Comment: I've marked your reply as an answer, because it helped a lot. However, I've did some additional measurements, which I cannot explain easily. I'll ask a separate question.